# Sending request from browser to ESP8266WebServer fails

Tags: xmlhttprequest, arduino-esp8266

I have a server in my ESP8266-01. The ESP8266 is in softAP mode. `ESP8266WebServer.h` is used to create the server.

When I type `192.168.4.1/1/` in the browser, it returns a UI containing buttons. The buttons are generated from the following code:

```
addToBuffer("<div class=\"row\">");
for(i=1; i<5; i++) {
    addToBuffer("<div class=\"col-md-2\"><button class=\"btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary\" id='btn_on");
    addToBuffer(clientId);
    addToBuffer(i);
    if(i==1)
        addToBuffer("'>UP</button></div>");
    if(i==2)
        addToBuffer("'>LEFT</button></div>");
    if(i==3)
        addToBuffer("'>RIGHT</button></div>");
    if(i==4)
        addToBuffer("'>DOWN</button></div>");
}
addToBuffer("</div>");

// JavaScript for buttons
addToBuffer("<script type='javascript'>");
for(i=1; i<5; i++) {
    addToBuffer("$('#btn_on");
    addToBuffer(clientId);
    addToBuffer(i);
    addToBuffer("').click(function(){var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();xmlHttp.open(\"GET\",'/");
    addToBuffer(clientId);
    addToBuffer("/");
    addToBuffer(i);
    addToBuffer("/',false);});");
    addToBuffer("xmlHttp.send(null);");
}
addToBuffer("</script>");
```

The server has handler functions for urls `/` `/1`, `/1/1/` `/1/2/` `/1/3/` `/1/4/`.

When I press any of the buttons, no request is being received in server. 
How to solve this?

Comment: In your browser check if htm jsl was rendered properly and also check when you click on buttons on browser does your browser really send a get request or not.?

Comment: which browser d you use ?

Comment: Google Chrome latest stable version.